# File timestamps disappear with SetFileTime() in File Explorer

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I use this code:

```
HANDLE handle = CreateFile( //Options// );
FILETIME time;
time.dwLowDateTime = time.dwHighDateTime = 0xFF;
SetFileTime(handle, &time, &time, &time);
```

When I use `0xFF` value in FILETIME struct with [`SetFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx) File Explorer shows blank date in Details Mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>). But if I open file properties it shows date as 02 Jan 1601.

- Can you explain why this date shows with `0xFF` value?

Comment: What date did _you_ expect?

Comment: Are you asking, why the API works as documented? That's hardly a useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date created via `time.dwLowDateTime = time.dwHighDateTime = 0xFF;` will be 0xFF000000FF * 100 ns later since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

This is about 30.4 hours, so the date may be 02 Jan 1601 (it may depend on the local timezone).

(reference: [FILETIME structure (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx))

Comment: @Biswapriyo _And why Windows explorer details mode can't show that time?_ Because there is probably a bug in the Windows explorer, or they deliberately chose not to display very old dates as these are wrong anyway (there was no Windows in 1601). For more details please read the [`FILETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx) reference